# Creating database by reading DbContext class generated from Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm fairly new to both C#, SQL and databases.

A couple of months ago I created a small project with a database that held about 4 simple tables. Using Entity Framework, I scaffolded a `DbContext` and entities for my database. However, that database is now gone (don't ask why) and in order to easily be able to run my project locally I need to recreate that database. The only thing I have is the `DbContext` and the generated entity classes.

Ideally I'd like to use that to do some magic with EF code first, but I realized it wasn't that simple.

Is there a easy way to recreate my DB? And if not, how can I easily interpret the `DbContext` (the `protected override void OnModelCreating()` method) in order to create the database manually, which I'm happy to do since the database is not that big. Only thing is I'm having a hard time mirroring the tables to match how the `DbContext` looks and doesn't quite understand how the `DbContext` was created.

Comment: If you used code-first in the project, you should only need to re-run all your migrations in a new database.

Comment: No I didn't. I used Database first to get my scaffolded entites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EF Core Power Tools to generate a SQL CREATE TABLE script from an existing DbContext